# Mapping cone as a Moore space

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Given an abelian group $G$ and natural number $n \geq 1$, a Moore space of type $(G,n)$ is a connected CW-complex $M(G,n)$ whose reduced homology is given by:

$\tilde{H}_i(M(G,n)) \cong
  \begin{cases}
    G       & \quad \text{if } i=n ,\\
    0  & \quad \text{ otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
$

I was able to describe how to construct a Moore space for finitely generated abelian $G$ but now I am stuck on something else. Let $K$ be a subgroup of $G$ ($G$ abelian), and let $\gamma:M(K,n) \rightarrow M(G,n)$ be a map of Moore spaces s.t. $\gamma$ induces the inclusion homomorphism on the $n$-th reduced homology. I want to show that the mapping cone $C_{\gamma}$ is a Moore space of type $M(G/K,n)$, but I am not really sure how to do this. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $M_\gamma$ be the mapping cylinder of $\gamma$, which is homotopy-equivalent to $M(G, n)$. Then the mapping cone $C_\gamma$ sits in a cofibre sequence

$$ M(K, n) \to M_\gamma \to C_\gamma $$

and therefore we get a long exact sequence of homology groups. This sequence is mostly zero, except the following segment:

$$ \dots \to 0 \to H_{n+1}(C_\gamma) \to H_n(M(K, n)) \to H_n(M_\gamma) \to H_n(C_\gamma) \to 0 \to \dots$$

Then $H_n(M(K, n)) \cong K$ and $H_n(M_\gamma)\cong H_n(M(G, n)) \cong G$ and the homomorphism is given by inclusion and hence is injective so $H_{n+1}(C_\gamma) \cong 0$, and by the first isomorphism theorem $H_n(C_\gamma) \cong G/K$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @William! It is probably trivial, but why can we go from a cofibre sequence to a long exact sequence of homology groups? If my understanding is correct, the map from $M(K,n)$ to $M_{\gamma}$ is a cofibration (thus injective)  and the map from $M_{\gamma}$ to $C_{\gamma}$ is just the quotient map, right? Is it obvious that their composition is $0$? The fact that $H_{n+1}(C_{\gamma}) \cong 0$  follows from what you stated plus the exactness of the sequence, is that correct?

Comment: You start with the long exact sequence of the pair $(M_\gamma, M(K, n))$ and then because the map is a cofibration it is a "good pair" in the sense of Hatcher so $H_n(M_\gamma, M(K, n)) \cong \tilde{H}_n(M_\gamma/ M(K, n)) = \tilde{H}_n(C_\gamma)$ (remember reduced vs unreduced only makes a difference when $n=0$). The composition $M(K, n) \to M_\gamma \to C_\gamma$ is a constant map. The computation of $H_n$ and $H_{n+1}$ of $G_\gamma$ follows from exactness of the sequence.

Comment: Ok, great, thank again!